# Super object codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a custom class called **Myclass** inside application/libraries.

Now as per the manual if i want to use the native resources i have to use the super object.

But if i just **extend Myclass just like any other controller** like the code below, i am able to load views, models etc without using the super object

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Myclass extends CI_Controller{

    public function my_func()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

}
```

**So why should i use the super object instead?**

Comment: I don't really understand what are you referring to under the "super object" name. What you describe is the intended way of using the framework.

Comment: If your 'Myclass' class extends CI_Controller...it should probably be in the application/controllers directory and act like a controller.

If you want to create your own LIBRARY though...you'll need to get the global CI object with the get_instance() function.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the base controller you should save it in `application/core`

From the manual [Extending core classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

> For example, to extend the native Input class you'll create a file
>   named application/core/MY_Input.php

I'm assuming here that you want to extend your controllers from `Myclass` instead of the `CI_Controller`.